# PHP Multi Dimensional Array Sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

### Edit : I need it to do only in Array Sort, As i am using procedure and sending it into json,

Here is my Table Structure,

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15c91/2)

[image]

I want to display as

2. alpha london
3. alpha newyork
4. beta  delhi
5. beta  sydney

I mean, the second coloumn (name) should be in Ascending Order and the third coloumn (place) should be in Descending Order.

How i want is

1. alpha london
2. alpha newyowk
3. beta delhi
4. beta sydney

**The Name should be in Asc Order and then to the right, the Place should be in Desc Order**

What i have tried so far is

How can i do this ??

```
<?php
include ('conn.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM test";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
foreach($result as $k=>$v)
{
echo $k;

}
}
?>
```

It displays the result as Invalid argument supplied to for each. What is the mistake i am doing and how can achieve my output

Comment: the way you want to display and the explanation you gave( I mean, the second coloumn (name) should be in Ascending Order and the third coloumn should be in Descending Order.... ) is confusing .please explain

Comment: I have updated my question in bold, kindly see it

Comment: if u want name in asc and place in desc dn desired output would b   alpha    newyork /  alpha london/beta sydney /beta  delhi

Answer (score 1):

To fix the sorting, just add ORDER BY name, place

Then there's several more issues preventing this from working:

1. You shouldn't call mysql_fetch_array outside the loop (this would discard the first row, alpha london in your example).
2. You need to iterate over `$rows`, not `$result` (this is where the "invalid argument" error is coming from).
3. You're not echoing the value; only the key. So you wouldn't be displaying the name and place at all; only the words "name" and "place".

You might want to do something like this to fix these:

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name, place";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  foreach ($rows as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k is $v. ";
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you do an order in your query itself like

```
SELECT * FROM test order by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only modifying query.

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name ASC, place DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

For your error, you are using wrong variable as foreach.
Replace this -

```
foreach($result as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k;
}
```

with this -

```
foreach($rows as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k;
}
```

Buy why are using foreach inside while loop. You can get your values like -

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $rows['name'].' '.$rows['place'].'<br/>';
}
```

and don't use `mysql_*` function. Use instead `mysqli_*`

And for your expected output, try using following query -

```
SELECT * FROM `test` order by name asc, place desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing you can fix using array_multisort.
Try the below example (which I have not tested yet, but ought to work)

```
<?php
include ('conn.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM test";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$totals = array();
$row = array();
$places = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $totals[] = $row
    $names[] = $row['name'];
    $places[] = $row['place'];
}
array_multisort( $names, SORT_ASC, $places, SORT_DESC, $totals );

// now you can use $totals, which is sorted as you want
print_r( $totals );
```